# Input fields becoming empty

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a function that inserts data to a database from a form, Whenever i use the masterpage and send the form to add a data, it breacks and stores nothing, the input fields seem to be empty.
but when i detach the masterpage, the functions works fine and data is stored eventually, i tried this with a new masterpage and the problem persists, i really don't know what is the problem.

Here is the MasterPage code :

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="backOffice_MasterPage" %>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="title">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" name="viewport" charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<!--Styles bootstrap-->
<link href="../styles/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../styles/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--Add a condition so that less than ie9 understands html5 tags such as header, article ...-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>       
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
     <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../scripts/jquery.1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/cyllene.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/ctrlsaisie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/CBrowser.js"></script>

<script src="../include/CEditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../include/CIconList.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Start Bootstrap
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ListPays.aspx">Liste des pays</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ListVilles.aspx">Liste des villes</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="ListActivites.aspx">Liste des activités</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
     <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">    
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cphMain" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->



<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->

<script src="../scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="script" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
```

And here is the page code :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"  AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/backOffice/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="GestPays.aspx.vb" Inherits="GestPays" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
<form id="FrmMain" runat="server">
<div class="frmContent">
    <afc:wccFilAriane ID="WccFilAriane1" runat="server">
        <afc:woStep ID="WoStep1" runat="server" Text="Accueil" NavigateUrl="../FrmAccueilGestion.aspx"></afc:woStep>
        <afc:woStep ID="WoStep3" runat="server" Text="Liste des pays" NavigateUrl="ListPays.aspx"></afc:woStep>
        <afc:woStep ID="WoStep2" runat="server" Text="Modification d'un pays" NavigateUrl="#"></afc:woStep>
    </afc:wccFilAriane>
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="KEY" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="C_PAGE" />
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle" Text="Pays" /></legend>
        <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLib" Text="Désignation" />
                                :
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="ID_LIBELLE" runat="server" />
                                <afc:wccMaskEdit ID="SYS_ID_LIBELLE" runat="server" MaxLength="250" Width="320px" />
                                <afc:wccPopUpCaller ID="TRAD_ID_LIBELLE" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/trad.gif" Visible="false"
                                    Text="Traduire" WindowHeigth="120" WindowWidth="550" Title="Traduction" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td style="height: 40px; vertical-align: top;">
                    <afc:wccButton runat="server" ID="btnValider" Text="Valider" Width="75px" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <afc:wccButton runat="server" ID="btnAnnuler" Text="Retour" Width="75px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

The code behind works fine when not using the masterpage so it's not necessarry i guess.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The <form> tags should be in the masterpage not the content page.

Comment: Yes, in fact that was the exact problém, even tough it would have been greater to use multiple forms in one page, but Ms though!
thank's brother

Answer (score 0):

The  tags should be in the masterpage not the content page